# Variables greyed out?

Tags: google-apps-script

New user.  My first question.

I'm retired now, but I used to work with Excel and VBA a little.  Now, I'm trying to help out a friend with a Google Sheets application.

My task is pretty simple.  Copy a range of data from one sheet and go to another sheet, go to the first empty row, and paste the data as values.

First of all, the variable **UHsheet** appears in pink text on my Apps Script screen, but the variables **oldRange** and **newRange** do not, they are both greyed out.  Not sure why that is, but I haven't been able to figure it out, and I'm thinking that might be my main issue.

Anyway, when I run this script, I get this error message:

**TypeError: oldRange.copyTo is not a function**.

Is this because Apps Script is not recognizing the **oldRange** variable?  If so, how do I fix it?

Thanks.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function SaveHistory() {
  var oldRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSelection();
  var UHsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Usage History');
  var newRange = (UHsheet.getLastRow() + 1);
oldRange.copyTo(newRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Comment: Pay attention to "types"/"classes". `oldRange` is not of type `Range`. `getSelection()` doesn't return a `Range`, but returns `Selection`. `Selection` doesn't have a `copyTo` method. Therefore, `oldRange.copyTo`  is not a function. You can use [`Selection.getActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection?hl=en#getActiveRange()) to get a range from `Selection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SaveHistory() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const uHsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Usage History');
  rg.copyTo(uHsheet.getRange(uHsheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Cooper!  That works great!  But why are you using Constants rather than Variables?

Comment: const can't be redefined and none of those should be redefined.  I always like to take the path that keeps me from making mistakes later on.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to "types"/"classes". `oldRange` is not of type `Range`. `getSelection()` doesn't return a `Range`, but returns `Selection`. `Selection` doesn't have a `copyTo` method. Therefore, `oldRange.copyTo`  is not a function. You can use [`Selection.getActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection?hl=en#getActiveRange()) to get a range from `Selection`:

```
const oldRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSelection().getActiveRange();
```

`newRange` is also not of type `Range`, but `Number`.